# Linux - Windows 8 - Samba - Can see dir and contents but not create

Tags: linux, permissions, windows, samba, file-sharing

have the following setup

Raspberry pi with samba installed and running

Windows 8 machine that can see the samba share, access the proper DIR, see all contents

In the smb.conf file, at the base of the file, I created the above dir with this

```
[AirLock]
comment = AirLock
path = /thepath/
writeable = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = Yes
public = Yes
read only = no
```

With these settings I can see the whole dir that I want but I cant create files, edit files, or create DIRs.

I need to do all of this.

Answer (score 1):

So after a TON of head ache the answer, as I suspected, was as simple as it was rediculous.

My smb.conf was fine

The problem was that I was attempting to create my share dir within /var/www and that dir didn't have write permission enabled.

I executed the following line and it all just worked from then on out.

```
sudo chmod 0777 /var/www
```

Comment: Careful with making things like /var/www 0777.  That means anyone and anything can create files in there.  And since presumably you are running a web server pointed there, any compromise in the web server allows arbritrary files to be created.

Comment: @kurtm I suspected that. Is there a way to limit that permission to an ip?

Comment: The filesystem knows nothing about IPs.  The web server would be enforcing that restriction, but if it gets compromised, the OS allows anyone to write anything in there.

Comment: @kurtm I suppose its very easy for me to just set those permissions when I need them. Thanks for the heads up