# What's the correct way to share a directory with Windows machines using Samba?

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I'm running Debian 7.7, intended to be used as a server. I've got Apache installed and I'd like to share its `/var/www` directory and access it from Windows machines. I've followed the instructions on the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SambaServerSimple) and a few other places, but I'm unable to get write access to the folders from Windows.

I apt-get installed samba, disabled home folder sharing, set `security = user`, added `aalaap` to the users list using `smbpasswd -a` and added the following share at the end of `smb.conf`:

```
[www]
    comment = Apache web root
    read only = no
    writable = yes
    valid users = @aalaap
    locking = no
    path = /var/www
    guest ok = yes
```

But when I access `\\debian\www`, I'm still unable to write to it (permission denied). Also, I can still see the `\\debian\aalaap` home profile, in spite of having disabled it.

I tried to map the www share in Windows and tried to login using `aalaap`, but Windows doesn't let me specify or disable the domain part, so it continues to log me in as `SURFACEPRO\aalaap`.

Needless to say, I've restarted Samba after nearly every step.

**Update:** I found [another similar question with a working answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93296/linux-windows-8-samba-can-see-dir-and-contents-but-not-create), but that required chmodding the folder 0777. It works, but that's obviously not secure, so I'd like to know what a better permissions set is.

Comment: Is aalaap a group? If not, does it help to  remove the "@" symbol from "valid users"?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I assumed that a group with the name of the user would include just that group. I haven't tried removing this, because it has worked fine after chmodding 0777. Just looking for a more secure way now...

Answer (score 1):

For now, I would suggest to just add the apache group (typically www-data) as a secondary group to every user in the aalaap group (or just the aalaap user)

[See 3rd section: Add a existing user to www-data group](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group-www-data/)

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data aalaap
sudo usermod -a -G www-data aalaap2
```

Assuming you have made apache the owner of **www**, and having set the needed permissions for the apache group, it seems to me more secure than authorizing everybody.

```
>ls -al /var  
... www-data www-data 4096 juin  18 22:53 www
```